# Mean image with two functions difference

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want process image so each pixel value will be mean of its value and 4 neighbours.

Created two different functions:

```
Mat meanImage(cv::Mat& inputImage)
{
    Mat output;
    Mat kernel(3,3,CV_32F,0.0);
    kernel.at<float>(0,1) = 0.2;
    kernel.at<float>(1,0) = 0.2;
    kernel.at<float>(1,1) = 0.2;
    kernel.at<float>(1,2) = 0.2;
    kernel.at<float>(2,1) = 0.2;
    filter2D(inputImage,output,-1,kernel);
    return output;
}
```

and:

```
Mat meanImage2(Mat& inputImage)
{
    Mat temp;
    Mat output(inputImage.rows,inputImage.cols,inputImage.type());
    copyMakeBorder(inputImage,temp,1,1,1,1,BORDER_REPLICATE);
    CV_Assert(output.isContinuous());
    CV_Assert(temp.isContinuous());
    const int len = output.rows * output.cols * output.channels();
    const int rowLenTemp = temp.cols * temp.channels();
    const int twoRowLenTemp = 2 * rowLenTemp;
    const int rowLen = output.cols * output.channels();
    uchar* outPtr = output.ptr<uchar>(0);
    uchar* tempPtr = temp.ptr<uchar>(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        const int a = 6 * (i / rowLen) + 3;
        outPtr[i] = (tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a] + tempPtr[i+a] + 
                    tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a+3] + tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a-3] +   
                    tempPtr[i+twoRowLenTemp+a]) / 5;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I've assumed that the result will be the same. So I've compared images:

```
Mat diff;
compare(meanImg1,meanImg2,diff,CMP_NE);
printf("Difference: %d\n",countNonZero(diff));
imshow("diff",diff);
```

And get a lot off differences. **What is the difference between this functions?**

Edit:
Difference for lena image taken from [Lena](http://www.hack4fun.org/h4f/sites/default/files/bindump/lena.bmp)

[image: Lena_diff]

Comment: What is the type of your images ?

Comment: you mean CV_**8**UC3 ?

Comment: Yes should be CV_8UC3.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that when you do the sum of pixels, you add `unsigned char`s and you may overflow.

Test your code by casting these pixels values to `int`.

```
outPtr[i] = ((int)tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a] + (int)tempPtr[i+a] + 
             (int)tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a+3] + (int)tempPtr[i+rowLenTemp+a-3] +   
             (int)tempPtr[i+twoRowLenTemp+a]) / 5;
```

**Edit**: I'd rather code this like (assuming image type is uchar and it has 3 channels)

```
for (int r = 0; r < output.rows; r++)
{
  uchar* previousRow = temp.ptr<uchar>(r) + 3; 
  uchar* currentRow = temp.ptr<uchar>(r+1) + 3; 
  uchar* nextRow = temp.ptr<uchar>(r+2) + 3; 

  uchar* outRow = output.ptr<uchar>(r);

  for (int c = 0; c < 3*output.cols; c++)
  {
    int value =              (int)previousRow[c] +  
      (int)currentRow[c-3] + (int)currentRow [c] + (int)currentRow[c+3] + 
                             (int)nextRow    [c];

    outRow[c] = value / 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for optimization suggestion. It's faster than my implementation. I've also applied suggestion of casting to int and see the possiblitity of overflow. Wired thing is that it makes no difference and I've tested it for different images. This answer does not answered my question. Result of your implementation is the same as with my implementation and still differs to `meanImage` with `cv::filter2D`.

Comment: It should be also `currentRow[c-3]` and `currentRow[c+3]` I've suggested edit.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the differences you observe, it may help us to solve your problem

Comment: Screenshot of difference added to question.